# connect to msql db using name rather the ip address using tablet

Tags: java, android

I am trying to connect to a msql db using tablet

my connection string is such like

```
       connString ="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.0.28:1433/foodserv;user=align;password=alignminds;";
```

it work fine .
Now i want to connect to the db using name of the server Like ip 10.0.0.28 has server name suresh-pc

Then how the string will change 
my point is to replace ip with name  and i am connection using tablet

Answer (score 0):

Server name is nothing but an alias for the IP of a host. If you use the server's name insted of IP the DNS server will resolve its ip for you. Check the link for ho DNS works http://www.howstuffworks.com/dns.htm. So simply replace the IP with server's name.

Comment: I changed my connection string to this  connection =  jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://JAGATH-PC:1433/foodserv;user=sa;password=alignminds;  But this is giving me error saying unabel to resolve host.   Well i am using a windows msql server and using android tablet as a client .

Comment: Make sure that your tablet and the server in the same network. If you have shell access please ping and check.

Comment: Yes both tablet and server are in same network and it is working fine with giving ip address but not with name

Comment: Can you able to connect from some other machine in the same network using server name.